# Catel + EntityFramework

Tags: wpf, database, entity-framework, mvvm, catel

I'm just a starter and asking a simple question.. Just need a direction where to move.
Can someone explain in very few words the process of application development using WPF+MVVM pattern (using Catel) with database created with Entity Framework.
1. I create models (Code First) and generate database
2. I create View models via Catel base classes
3. I create Views with WPF

The question is: how to connect database with Catel View Models? Where to load DBContext and entities? Should I create repositories? Or maybe it's needed to create separate Models?
Is there a common way or maybe example of a small WPF application which uses database to store data?

Sorry if my question is slightly heretic - simply can't sort all the terms and approaches into a single system which I will follow during app creation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there are technical discussions in the field what is best way, there are two commonly used scenarios:

1) Using repositories (Catel does support implementations of repositories for both EF5 and EF6)
2) Use a service that will handle the functions and call that in the view model like any other service.

Comment: Big thanks, Geert. You do incredible work. Will continue reading your documentation.